# python IndexError: out of range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm using this little snippet of code and apparently the index is out of range? I can't see why but it's giving me the error.

```
Grid = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]

def SpawnNumber(Grid):
    # Check is true when the random grid space is a 0
    check = False
    # Loop until an empty space is chosen
    while check == False:
        rn1 = randint(0,3)
        rn2 = randint(0,3)
        print(rn1)
        print(rn2)
        # If the space is empty, fill it
        if Grid[rn1][rn2] == 0:
            Grid[rn1][rn2] = 2
            check = True
    return(Grid)
```

Grid should have two dimensions, each going from 0-3 so why is randint(0,3) going out of range?

Comment: `rn1` should only be from 0-1. You only have two sublists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid has only 2 elements with indexes 0 and 1. You can do a quick check by evaluating len(Grid). I.e. rn1 can only have the values 0 and 1.

Comment: IN short, just change the code so that rn1 is constrained to 0 or 1 and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the "Grid" you are sending in doesn't have items in the indexes you expect.

To allow your function to be more general and digest any variety of grids passed in you could do something like:

```
def SpawnNumber(Grid):
    # Check is true when the random grid space is a 0
    check = False
    # Loop until an empty space is chosen
    while check == False:
        rn1 = randint(0,len(Grid)-1)
        rn2 = randint(0,len(Grid[rn1])-1)
        print(rn1)
        print(rn2)
        # If the space is empty, fill it
        if Grid[rn1][rn2] == 0:
            Grid[rn1][rn2] = 2
            check = True
    return(Grid)
```

The -1 being in there because of the inclusive logic of RandInt.  Per the docs:

```
random.randint(a, b)
    Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b
```

A minor style note: as written this function has an issue that if there are no empty spaces found it will go into an infinite loop.  So having some sort of break out logic is advised.  If you know the grid will only ever go one element deep, you could do something like:

```
def SpawnNumber(Grid):
    # Check is true when the random grid space is a 0
    check = False
    # Check if there are any open spots
    for row in Grid:
        if all(row):
            check = True
    # Loop until an empty space is chosen
    while check == False:
        rn1 = randint(0,len(Grid)-1)
        rn2 = randint(0,len(Grid[rn1])-1)
        print(rn1)
        print(rn2)
        # If the space is empty, fill it
        if Grid[rn1][rn2] == 0:
            Grid[rn1][rn2] = 2
            check = True
    return(Grid)
```